# webpack-dev-server with Rails returns 400 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have several projects on my machine with Rails and webpacker.
One started doing me the following:
Running webpack-dev-server along with rails server, everything compiles, but when trying to access the /packs/xxxx.js or .css I get 400 error (Bad Request) -> No errors are shown in the consoles.

This is my webpacker.yml

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .vue
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 3035
    public: 127.0.0.1:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

What can be wrong???
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hey I also ran into this error, after few investigations I figured out that something was wrong with my cookies...

I know it can sound silly, but if you still have this problem I'd advice to try with another Chrome session or another browser.

If this does the trick, then just clear your cookies, you should be good to go.

Hope this helps others.

N.B : This problem is not only occurring within Rails, all my others projects involving `webpack-dev-server` were broken.

Comment: Was indeed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same issue by:

- Stopping `webpacker-dev-server`
- Stopping `rails server`
- Running `rm -r tmp/cache/webpacker` in the project root
- Restarting the server
- Refreshing the page